# Most efficient way to store and traverse this data?

Tags: php, xml, database, arrays

I want to check a blog post for occurrences of specific foreign words, and then link those words to sound files so they can be played.

I have an XML file with 2500 words that I have sound files for, and I'm wondering what's the best way to store and traverse this list? The list isn't likely to change, and the function will be run on each blog post when viewed in full (not when excerpts are shown on archive pages etc).

The XML file is 350KB, which I was loading into PHP with simplexml_load_file. I thought this was a bit large, so I converted it into a PHP file containing an indexed (by string) array of the words, which brings the file size down to about 60KB.

Should I be worrying so much about the file size, or more about how much time it will take to search through the data? Is there a better way of doing this or would it be best in a database? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is it an optiion to cache the data using memcached ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you find parsing and matching the XML file against the blogpost happens within reasonable time, then there is no need to optimize. Optimize when you notice any significant negative impact.

The easiest approach would probably be to simply cache the processed pages. Whenever the blog post or the word list changes, invalidate the cache, so it gets processed anew the next time it's called.

Answer (score 0):

Converting your file into a PHP array is just great (you can't do better than that performance-wise unless you go into writing your own extension). Not only is the input file smaller, but you have also taken care of a pretty CPU-heavy (in relation to your other operations) XML-parsing step.

An objection could have been raised because an array will force you to read all of the data in at once, but weighing in at 60K that's no problem.

As for searching the data, since PHP arrays are associative they offer pretty good performance in this kind of scenario.

Overall I 'd say your approach is the correct one.

Comment: "a pretty CPU-heavy [...] XML-parsing step" ...and replaced it with a pretty CPU-heavy PHP-parsing step. Or how do you think, the PHP interpreter gets to know what to do? Actually, a good XML stream parser like Expat might be the next-to-best solution apart from storing the values in a DB.

Comment: @Boldewyn: True, there would be a PHP parsing cost. I believe it would be significantly faster (if nothing else, 350KB vs 60KB to parse), plus it would be amenable to opcode caching. Based on experience, I still think this is the best way apart from caching the end result itself.

Comment: I was concerned about the time it would take to parse the array, I'm basically doing "if(!empty($words[$match]))" to check if the word exists in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing based on the array of words stored in a file is time consuming than searching  in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Without doubt the most extensible solution to this is to use a database.  This can handle huge amounts of data without significant performance drops, so if you had more data in future it would be trivial to add it.  In this case, you could use [`sqlite`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php), which requires fairly little in terms of installation and configuration and yet is fairly quick and powerful.

Your solution using a PHP array (presumably using `include`/`require`) is a pretty good one, and I wouldn't worry too much about changing it.  You are absolutely right, however, to lose the XML file.  That would be both excessively labour-intensive and slow.